# unable to compile brian gladman aes library

Tags: c++, c, gcc, aes, centos

I have been compiling brian gladman's library from here www.gladman.me.uk
I am able to compile the lib on my local machine(ubuntu 10.10) but when I try to compile on my remote machine(CentOs 5.4) it generates numerous errors with **gcc** ..

The error generated are [here](http://pastebin.com/fQM4t6Dx)

thankx in adv ..

Comment: Why not try looking at `aes_via_ace.h` line 401 to see what the problem might be ???

Comment: @paul sorry am a newbie to c programming ,can u tell me what the issue is and why is it working on one machine and not on another..

Comment: why not post line 401 from `aes_via_ace.h`, then the problem may be obvious.

Comment: INLINE volatile  void via_ecb_op5(const void *k, const void *c, const void *s, void *d, int l)
{//line no 401 contains only this single bracket

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first error in your compilation is

```
brg_types.h:138:6: error: #error Please define uint_64t as an unsigned 64 bit type in brg_types.h
```

(before are only warnings which might point to problems, but they don't cause your compile to break.)

The problem there is that BRG_UI64 was not defined, more specifically the type uint_64t. The definition takes place previously. Most of the following problems exist because uint_64t is not defined, so the same reason.

Essentially it looks among different unsigned types for the first that has a max value of 18446744073709551615u, i.e. a complete unsigned 64bit integer and defines that as uint_64t. If no type is found the above error is raised by using #error.

So it seems neither of UINT_MAX, ULONG_MAX, ULLONG_MAX or  ULONG_LONG_MAX is 18446744073709551615 on your remote system.

You can check the values of your constants with a simple program

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  double d;

#if defined( UINT_MAX )
  d = UINT_MAX;
  printf("UINT_MAX is %f\n", d );
#if UINT_MAX == 18446744073709551615u
  printf("UINT_MAX satisfies condition\n");
#endif
#endif
#if defined( ULONG_MAX )
  d = ULONG_MAX;
  printf("ULONG_MAX is %f\n", d );
#if ULONG_MAX == 18446744073709551615ul
  printf("ULONG_MAX satisfies condition\n");
#endif
#endif
#if defined( ULLONG_MAX )
  d = ULLONG_MAX;
  printf("ULLONG_MAX is %f\n", d );
#if ULLONG_MAX == 18446744073709551615ull
  printf("ULLONG_MAX satisfies condition\n");
#endif
#endif
#if defined( ULONG_LONG_MAX )
  d = ULONG_LONG_MAX;
  printf("ULONG_LONG_MAX is %f\n", d );
#if ULONG_LONG_MAX == 18446744073709551615ull
  printf("ULONG_LONG_MAX satisfies condition\n");
#endif
#endif

  return 0;
}
```

There are several versions of limits.h and climits (which is included by some of the c++-includes) on my system (and perhaps on yours as well). You can find them with

```
find /usr/include -name '*limits*'
```

I can't help you porting the library anyway. I don't think defining a type on your own is a good idea if you don't know what you are doing (though an unsigned integer type with a bigger max value might work).

If a different compiler doesn't solve the problem for you it is probably best if you contact the author for a fix.

Those constants are system and compiler-dependent. So reasons why it works on your local, but not on the remote machine might be:

- One is a 32-bit machine, the other 64-bit
- Different version of gcc
- Ubuntu and CentOS install a different limit.h

Here is the code for those who might have more insight into those platform dependent stuff than me.

```
#include <limits.h>
...
#ifndef BRG_UI64
#  if defined( __BORLANDC__ ) && !defined( __MSDOS__ )
#    define BRG_UI64
#    define li_64(h) 0x##h##ui64
     typedef unsigned __int64 uint_64t;
#  elif defined( _MSC_VER ) && ( _MSC_VER < 1300 )    /* 1300 == VC++ 7.0 */
#    define BRG_UI64
#    define li_64(h) 0x##h##ui64
     typedef unsigned __int64 uint_64t;
#  elif defined( __sun ) && defined( ULONG_MAX ) && ULONG_MAX == 0xfffffffful
#    define BRG_UI64
#    define li_64(h) 0x##h##ull
     typedef unsigned long long uint_64t;
#  elif defined( __MVS__ )
#    define BRG_UI64
#    define li_64(h) 0x##h##ull
     typedef unsigned int long long uint_64t;
#  elif defined( UINT_MAX ) && UINT_MAX > 4294967295u
#    if UINT_MAX == 18446744073709551615u
#      define BRG_UI64
#      define li_64(h) 0x##h##u
       typedef unsigned int uint_64t;
#    endif
#  elif defined( ULONG_MAX ) && ULONG_MAX > 4294967295u
#    if ULONG_MAX == 18446744073709551615ul
#      define BRG_UI64
#      define li_64(h) 0x##h##ul
       typedef unsigned long uint_64t;
#    endif
#  elif defined( ULLONG_MAX ) && ULLONG_MAX > 4294967295u
#    if ULLONG_MAX == 18446744073709551615ull
#      define BRG_UI64
#      define li_64(h) 0x##h##ull
       typedef unsigned long long uint_64t;
#    endif
#  elif defined( ULONG_LONG_MAX ) && ULONG_LONG_MAX > 4294967295u
#    if ULONG_LONG_MAX == 18446744073709551615ull
#      define BRG_UI64
#      define li_64(h) 0x##h##ull
       typedef unsigned long long uint_64t;
#    endif
#  endif
#endif
```

Comment: . I checked for u suggestions , I have both systems on 32 bit and both have same limits.h file installed, But the gcc version is diff i.e gcc-4.4 (local)  and gcc-4.1(remote) , But I tried to compile it on two more machines with same config as local , it worked on one and failed with same errors on another..

Comment: Added some code for you to determine the different constants and find all possibly used limits-versions. I fear that is the limit of my knowledge in that area. I don't know the interdependencies of the different files in a gcc installation on Linux.

Comment: . I followed that file and got same values on both machines .UINT_MAX is 4294967295.000000
ULONG_MAX is 4294967295.000000
ULLONG_MAX is 18446744073709551616.000000
ULONG_LONG_MAX is 18446744073709551616.000000

Comment: Ok, I played around with it on my machine (modified the code of the test program a very little bit to work with C-compiler). I found that if I save that file as test.c and compile it has different results for gcc (compile as C-source) and g++ (compile as C++ source). With gcc there is only UINT_MAX and ULONG_MAX (both too small), but with g++ there is everything and ULLONG_MAX unad ULONG_LONG_MAX are big enough. Perhaps you should try to use g++ for compiling... Maybe your systems have a different behaviour to when each compiler is to be used, but this is only guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

The first error is on brg_types.hat line 138;

```
brg_types.h:138:6: error: #error Please define uint_64t as an unsigned 64 bit type in brg_types.h
```

I found [here](http://mirror.seize.it/SimpleAES/cbits/brg_types.h) a online copy of that file (maybe a different version). So you need to find how to create a 64 bit unsigned integer, and add some defines above that line, for example

```
#define BRG_UI64
#define li_64(h) 0x##h##ull
typedef unsigned long long uint_64t;
```

if `unsigned long long` is 64 bit and you enter literal numbers like `0x123456789ull`.

And it looks like there will be more porting required to compile this on your compiler.